# Unable to open connection pooling error when using ODBC with Mono on Red Hat Linux

Tags: c#, linux, mono, openedge

We are working with Mono in RedHat 6.5.  We are trying to connect to a local database using ODBC.  When we try to connect we get an error message ERROR - Unable to enable connection pooling.  I have tried to disable pooling by setting Pooling=false; in the connection string.

The exact same code works fine on Windows 7. Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Using PHP we are able to connect to the database without any issues.  Its a Progress OpenEdge database if that makes any difference.

Here is our setup.

odbcinst.ini is setup as follows:

```
[Progress]                                                                      
Description     = ODBC for Progress                                             
Driver          = /usr/dlc64Bit/odbc/lib/pgoe27.so                              
FileUsage       = 1                                                             

[ODBC]                                                                          
Pooling         = True                                                          
Trace           = Yes                                                           
TraceFile               = /home/rr/progress/trace.log                           
UseCursorLib            = 1                                                     
UsageCount              = 2
```

odbc.ini is setup as follows:

```
[my_progress]                                                                   
Driver=Progress                                                                 
Description=Test to Progress                                                    
DatabaseName=pt                                                                 
PortNumber=9003                                                                 
HostName=localhost                                                          
LoginID=                                                                        
Password=                                                                       
APILevel=1                                                                      
ConnectFunctions=YYN                                                            
CPTimeout=60                                                                    
DriverODBCVer=03.60                                                             
FileUsage=0                                                                     
SQLLevel=0                                                                      
UsageCount=1                                                                    
ArraySize=50                                                                    
DefaultLongDataBuffLen=2048                                                     
DefaultIsolationLevel=REPEATABLE READ                                           
StaticCursorLongColBuffLen=4096
```

The ODBC works fine using PHP!

Here is the Mono program:

```
using System;                                                                   
using System.Data;                                                              
using System.Data.Odbc;                                                         

public class Test                                                               
{                                                                               
    string connectionString, sql;                                           

    public void testProgress()                                              
    {                                                                       
        System.Console.WriteLine("Testing Progress");                   
        connectionString =                                              
            "DSN=my_progress;" +                                    
            "UID=root;" +                                           
            "PWD=root;" + 
            "Pooling=false";                                             
        sql =                                                        
            "SELECT productcode, prodtype FROM pub.locations";      

    }                                                                       
    public void testConnection()                                            
    {                                                                       
        try
        {                                                               
            IDbConnection dbcon;                                    
            dbcon = new OdbcConnection(connectionString);           
            dbcon.Open();                                           
            IDbCommand dbcmd = dbcon.CreateCommand();               
            dbcmd.CommandText = sql;                                
            IDataReader reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();             
            while(reader.Read()) {                                  
                string product = (string) reader["productcode"];

                string producttype = (string) reader["prodtype"];                                                                               
                Console.WriteLine(product + " " + producttype); 
            }                                                       
            // clean up                                             
            reader.Close();                                         
            reader = null;                                          
            dbcmd.Dispose();                                        
            dbcmd = null;                                           
            dbcon.Close();                                          
            dbcon = null;                                           
        }                                                               
        catch(Exception ex)
        {                                                               
            System.Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);       
        }                                                               
    }                                                                       

    public static void Main(string[] args)                                  
    {                                                                       
        Test test = new Test();                                         
        test.testProgress();                                            
        test.testConnection();                                          
    }                                                                       
}
```

When I run the program after compiling it, I get the following error:

Error - unable to enable connection pooling

Comment: Consider providing some code and the connection string as well.

Answer (score 0):

Connection pooling is not supported by Progress OpenEdge Wire Protocol Driver. See documentation:

- [Advanced Features/Using DataDirect Connection
  Pooling](http://media.datadirect.com/download/docs/odbc/allodbc/help.html?_ga=1.147499255.174995294.1392110067#page/odbc/using-datadirect-connection-pooling.html#)
- [OpenEdge Knowledgebase - About ODBC Connection pooling on UNIX / Linux](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/6297?q=odbc%20unix%20pooling&l=en_US&fs=Search&pn=1)

> ODBC connection pooling on UNIX/Linux is not implemented in the ODBC Driver manager.
>   Instead it is implemented in (some of) the DataDirect ODBC drivers.

but it looks like it is used by default in .NET/Mono:

.../mono-4.2.3/external/referencesource/System.Data/System/Data/Odbc/**OdbcEnvironmentHandle.cs**:

```
 ...
 //Turn on connection pooling
 //Note: the env handle controls pooling.  Only those connections created under that
 //handle are pooled.  So we have to keep it alive and not create a new environment
 //for   every connection.
 //
 retcode = UnsafeNativeMethods.SQLSetEnvAttr(
            this,
            ODBC32.SQL_ATTR.CONNECTION_POOLING,
            ODBC32.SQL_CP_ONE_PER_HENV,
            ODBC32.SQL_IS.INTEGER);

        switch(retcode) {
        case ODBC32.RetCode.SUCCESS:
        case ODBC32.RetCode.SUCCESS_WITH_INFO:
            break;
        default:
            Dispose();
            throw ODBC.CantEnableConnectionpooling(retcode);
        }
 ...
```

I'm getting the following exception (using your example code adjusted to my environment - Linux, Ubuntu 14.04, Mono JIT compiler version 4.2.3 (Stable 4.2.3.4/832de4b Wed Mar 16 13:19:08 UTC 2016) ):

```
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: 
System.InvalidOperationException: ERROR - unable to enable connection pooling...
----->>> at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcEnvironmentHandle <<-----..ctor () <0x411a0b80 + 0x00097> in <filename unknown>:0
            --------------------------------------
at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcEnvironment.GetGlobalEnvironmentHandle () <0x411a05c0 + 0x000bf> in <filename unknown>:0
...
```